# negative lookahead seems to match what it is not supposed to

Tags: regex

given the content:

```
hello bob
hello my name is bob
```

I am trying to match `hello bob` using a negative lookahead.  The regex `hello.*(?!my name is).*bob` matches both lines.  The regex `hello .*(?!my name is) .*bob` matches the second line.

How can I match just the first line, and why on earth does the negative lookahead match the line that it's supposed to NOT match against?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greedy `.*` before the negative lookahead is what's keeping it from working correctly.  This does the match you're looking for:

```
/hello (?!my name is).*bob/
```

Alternatively, you can put the `.*` into the negative assertion directly:

```
/hello(?!.*my name is).*bob/
```

That'll keep the two from competing.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Can you explain why .* being greedy before the negative lookahead caused it to break?

Comment: Your original regex is saying "I want 'hello', followed by anything, not followed by 'my name is', followed by anything, followed by 'bob.'"  In this case, you get 'hello,' followed by anything -- the anything being 'my name is.' There's no 'my name is' after that anything, so you get a match.

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookahead is overkill if you only need to match the first thing, so this regex should be enough:

```
^hello bob$
```

Using the start of line anchor (`^`) and the end of line anchor (`$`), only `hello bob` will satisfy that regex.